# Areas in session based testing test chart

Tags: test-design, exploratory, sbtm

I am not sure how to distinguish the chart and the areas in it...
For me, the chart describes in one sentence what the session is all about.

And the areas are a (probably incomplete) high-level description of what will be done in a session.

For example:
Test chart: Login with a different type of user

Areas:

Login with a non-registered user.
Login with a registered user.
Login with the wrong credentials.
etc.

Is this correct or too much "fake" session? I mean, I am not describing script test cases (since no test steps) but high level what I will test.

Some of my testers just copy the acceptance criteria of a user story in the area and say: "this is my session".

Answer (score 1):

Taking for example [James Bach's charter template](https://www.satisfice.com/download/session-based-test-management)

- The Charter entry is a description of your testing goals, what do you want to explore and which information do you want to extract or understanding you are after.
- The Areas you can include the components, environment, testing techniques, etc. Basically everything that will describe the tooling and the points of the SUT that you want to explore.

[image]

Comment: So, there will not something like highlevel test scenarios desciption before the session anywhere?

Comment: The Charter is an output document for a testing session. Naturally you can pre-fill it or some other note with test ideas, but it's not the main purpose of it.